# Not able to execute citrus test case xmls with citrus version 2.7.4 and above

Tags: citrus-framework

While running citrus tests defined in xmls with citrus version 2.7.4 and above the frame work is not executing test cases. But with 2.7.3 the xml tests are getting executed. here is my [console   output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4GWu.jpg)

here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.walmart.testframrework</groupId>
  <artifactId>testframework</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
  <groupId>com.consol.citrus</groupId>
  <artifactId>citrus-mail</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.6</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.consol.citrus</groupId>
  <artifactId>citrus-java-dsl</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.6</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.consol.citrus</groupId>
    <artifactId>citrus-jms</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency> 
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.25</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.25</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.consol.citrus</groupId>
      <artifactId>citrus-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.6</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Could any one please help on this

Comment: Your console output show that 2 tests ran without failed with 2.7.6. Your question is a bit confused

Comment: yes it was just showing like that if i change the version citrus as 2.7.3 in pom file it will show which action are executed and which testcase is executed. The console out put would not be like this as shown in the picture if test case xml are executed

Answer (score 0):

You are having a logging framework issue in your project. The console log complains about multiple slf4j bindings in your classpath. In addition to that I suggest to review the log4j configuration for loggers and levels.

Your tests get executed but the logging events are not printed to the console for these reasons.